# Counting and combining rows across multiple tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

I would like to count the number of occurrences of a variable in rows across multiple tables and then combine them to get an output like the following:

```
Output Table

user id | A count | B count | C count | Total count   
------------------------------------------------
1       |     *   |    *    |    *    |    *
2       |     *   |    *    |    *    |    *
3       |     *   |    *    |    *    |    *
```

From tables with the following structure:

```
Table A, B, C etc

   x    |    y   |  user id  |   
-------------------------------
   *    |    *   |     2
   *    |    *   |     4
   *    |    *   |     1
   *    |    *   |     1
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782434/counting-and-combining-rows) deals with counting in a single table but I'm unsure how to apply the solution across multiple tables to get the output shown above. Ideally I'd then output to CSV. Any help would be much appreciated.

EXAMPLE DATA (see comments to answer marked correct)

```
user_id     a        b         c       a+b+c
1           18266    238640    2022    258928
70          67       200       19      286
596         2        3         6       11
759         56       606       67      729
760         2        5         5       12
1122        194      1030      220     1444
1194        26       2         2       30
1298        195      466       2       663
```

Comment: Could you clarify what are columns 'x' and 'y' in A, B,C tables?

Comment: x and y are columns i'm not interested in counting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(a), SUM(b), SUM(c), SUM(a) + SUM(b) + SUM(c)
FROM
(
   SELECT user_id, count(*) a, 0 b, 0 c FROM A GROUP BY user_id
    UNION ALL
   SELECT user_id, 0, count(*), 0 FROM B GROUP BY user_id
    UNION ALL
   SELECT user_id, 0, 0, count(*) FROM C GROUP BY user_id
) tmp
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: what do the lower case letters refer to? Is A1 different from A? thanks.

Comment: lower case letters are just an alias for count value. Aliases are used to be referred from outer SELECT. A1, B1, C1 are also alises. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: Ah sure. I get the correct output format but very few results - I only get results for entries with a non-zero in every column. Does the query ignore rows with a 0 value for the column in any of the tables?

Comment: please see example data in the question. The entire output is shown. Out of about 300,000 entries there are none with 0 in any column. The ones shown all have count values of > 0

Comment: I've completely update query. Please try in fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12bd4/1